# Reverse a LinkedList c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, reversing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to reverse a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521452/unable-to-reverse-a-linked-list)

I'm trying to reverse a linked list:

```
void LinkedList::reverseList()
{
    Node *next=_head;
    Node *prev=0;
    while(next!=0)
    {
        Node *tmp=next->_next;
        next->_next=prev;
        prev=next;
        next=tmp;
    }
}
```

Lets say the list is: 4->3->2->1

When I print the list, I only see 1 (The print function is good).

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's C++, give Node some methods. Let them swap their places in the list without swapping their values.

Then find both ends of the list and swap them, working your way along until you either reach the same node at both ends or the ones you've just swapped.

Comment: You never assign `_head`, do you?

Comment: Add `_head = prev;` after `while` loop.

Comment: I tried, that didn't help. I still get >>1 as an output.

Comment: It should, really. If you add `_head = prev` after the `while` loop, your code is exactly identical to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4908881/500104). I've also tried and verified it on [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f42689ac1565bb3f9947076247e624f3).

Comment: Thank you Xeo, my printList function may cause the problem.. although
it prints it good before the reversing.

Comment: Indeed.. I called it once before and once after the reversing.. (I traveled with _head itself.. that caused the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you wanted to find the problem on your own, I'll just give you a hint instead of the solution.

Your `reverse` function works in that it successfully reverses the list.  That isn't the problem.  You probably have 2 calls to `print`.  One before and one after the reverse.  What do you note about the nodes being passed to `print` in both cases?  What does that tell you?

EDIT:

Since you said you've found the problem, I'll post the actual solution.

In your `reverse` code, you never update the `_head` of the list, but when you `reverse` the list, the head does actually change from `4` to `1`.  Since you never update `_head`, when you call `print` the second time (after the `reverse` call) you start printing at `1`,  That being the end of the list, that's the only node printed.

The solution is to update `_head` when you reverse the list.  The simplest way to do this is to simply update it in each iteration.  This may be slightly less efficient than other possible solutions, but it doesn't change the time complexity of the algorithm -- it's still O(n):

```
void LinkedList::reverseList()
{
    Node *next=_head;
    Node *prev=0;
    while(next!=0)
    {
        Node *tmp=next->_next;
        next->_next=prev;
        _head = next;
        prev=next;
        next=tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The printList function doesn't receive any parameters, it begins with the _head and then travels until the end of the list (until 0 is the next of the last node)..

Comment: Now I get it.. thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Do you want me to post the solution now?

Comment: Sure.. now I fixed it :) I should have "traveled" on a copy of _head and not _head itself on the print function.

Comment: @Maroun: Ouch, that is a bad idea, yeah. :) You would've noticed that if you made your `print` member `const`, though! As in `void print() const{ ... }`.

Comment: Indeed.. 'const' can save a lot of time :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

**Doubly-linked list:**

```
for (Node * n = _head, * next; ; n = next)
{
    next = n->next;

    std::swap(n->next, n->prev);

    if (next == NULL) { _head = n; break; }
}
```

**Singly-linked list:**

```
for (Node * n = _head, * prev = NULL, * next; ; prev = n, n = next)
{
    next = n->next;

    n->next = prev;

    if (next == NULL) { _head = n; break; }
}
```

Comment: My first thought exactly, but it appears to be a single-linked list.

Comment: There's never any mention of `n->prev`. :)

Comment: OK, I made two versions, one for a double and one for a single list.

Comment: I'll try this one.. Can someone explain why my code doesn't work? What I'm missing here?

Comment: @Maroun85: Didn't Xeo already explain it? You never reassign `_head` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I like recursion; It's easier to grasp and verify;

```
Node* LinkedList::reverseList() { // returns tail
  if (!_head || !_head->_next)
      return _head;
  Node* const h = _head;
  _head = _head->_next;
  h->_next = NULL;
  return reverseList()->_next = h;
}
```